# Actionscript - AS 2.0 - PHP copy file from server to server THEN run function

Tags: php, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, file-transfer

**Basic Idea:** I have a flash file that takes screenshots with a click of a button, sending the data to a PHP file, and then the user gets to save a PNG image.  The images that are merged together (via PHP) require that they reside on the same server as the PHP, otherwise they do not merge and the final PNG shows up blank.

**My solution so far:** I have two PHP files, and I just need to find a way to merge them.  The screenshot one, and one that copies a file from one server to another.  This is my cheat work around to bring the image to reside on the same server, THEN run the screenshot php.

**The Server-to-Server PHP Code:**

```
<?PHP

$inputfile = FOPEN("https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png", "r");
$outputfile = FOPEN("transferedfile.gif", "w");
ECHO "File opened...";
$data = '';

WHILE (!FEOF($inputfile)) {
  $data .= FREAD($inputfile, 8192);
}

ECHO "Data read...";
FWRITE($outputfile, $data);
ECHO "transfered data";
FCLOSE ($inputfile);
FCLOSE ($outputfile);

ECHO "Done.";

?>
```

So as you can see, it pulls Google's logo and saves it as "transferedfile.gif" to the directory the PHP resides on.  I can get this PHP code to work by saving this as whateverIWant.php on my webserver, and visiting it directly, but I need to in place of Google's logo (in this example) put a value that will be dynamically changing via flash.

So basically… in the flash file, I'll have a dyniamic variable where the URL will change, in short.  So we'll just say that I define that variable in flash as `var imageToGet` so somehow I need to pass that variable into this PHP.  That's one step... here's the AS 2.0 code:

**My Actionscript (2.0) Code:**

```
button.onRelease = function ():Void {
    sendImageToServer();
    ScreenShot.save(_root, "screenshot.png", 0, 0, 100, 140);
};
```

the `sendImageToServer()` function isn't made yet.  This is where I'm stuck.  I would need the `sendImageToServer()` function to send `var imageToGet` as what image to get, THEN run the `ScreenShot.save()` function after the transfer is done (aka `FCLOSE ($outputfile);` is complete)

**In Summary:** A movie clip on the stage will have a dynamic image loaded into it, that once a button is pressed, it would need to copy that dynamic image to the local server, and then run the screenShot function.  I believe once I have this figured out, I should be able to do everything else, such as saving as a unique name, saving multiple files, etc.  But I just need pushed in the right direction :)

Thanks so much everyone @ StackOverflow.  You've been nothing but awesome to me thus far!

**EDIT -- I've found a good starting point!!**

I found a good starting point, and am answering my own question in case someone else stumbles upon this.  I used these two codes as a starting point, and I think I'm on the right track…

**In Flash:** I simply made a dynamic textbox with the instance name of `traceText`

**In Actionscript (2.0):**

```
var send:LoadVars = new LoadVars;
var receive:LoadVars = new LoadVars;
send.toPHP = "asd123";
receive.onLoad = function(){
encrypted = this.toFlash;
traceText.text = encrypted;
}
send.sendAndLoad("test.php",receive,"POST");
```

**In "test.php" file:**

```
$fromFlash = $_POST['toPHP'];
$encrypted = $fromFlash;
$toFlash = "&toFlash=";
$toFlash .= $encrypted;
echo $toFlash;
```

What this ended up doing was sending the variable to PHP and then back again.  Which is perfect for what I needed.  For now, I should be good!  Hope this helps anyone that needs it.